# Get strings between double quotation marks also keeping text inbetween

Tags: javascript, regex, text, split

I have this text:

`"Hello" he said "how are you?"`

and I want to split it wherever quotes are, but I want to keep 2 corresponding quotes together,  so I'd like to get:

`[ 
   "\"Hello\"" , 
   " he said ", 
   "\"how are you?\"" 
 ]`

How would I do this? I know I can get just the quoted text like so: `"(.*?)"/g`, but that does skip the other parts of the text. Some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `.split()` with your regex (although instead of `.*?`, it is advisable to use a more efficient and also matching line breaks character class, `[^"]*`) enclosed within a capturing group:

```js
console.log(
    '"Hello" he said "how are you?"'.split(/("[^"]*")/).filter(Boolean)
)
```

Output:

```
[
  "\"Hello\"",
  " he said ",
  "\"how are you?\""
]
```

The `.filter(Boolean)` will omit empty strings from the resulting array.